# Cannot access ubuntu server guest on virtualbox hosted on network windows xp machine

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-xp, ssh, virtualbox

I managed to create a mediawiki for our knowledge database at work as my personal project. This is running on ubuntu server 12.04 on virtualbox.

This was on my local machine due to setup steps, but now I have to move it to a network open server, which is this Wxp machine...

What I can do:

- I have full access thru mstsc to the XP machine.
- by accessing the xp machine, I can run and therefore access the vbox console.
- I can ping the xp from my own pc.

The problem is that I can't connect to virtualbox using the basic port forward from other network machines.

what I did until now:

- tried to set virtualbox on bridge mode, but I don't know why, ubuntu
  can't acquire network configs...
- It only works in NAT. From the xp host machine, I forwarded the localhost:4590 port to 10.0.2.15:80, which allows me to connect from the host (xp) to the wiki on localhost:4590/wiki
- on the host machine, control panel/firewall, I created two exceptions. One for port 22 (so I can ssh to server) and 4590 to access the wiki.

In a web search, i found this command to be used on CMD, but I'm afraid to mess with the server connections if I do anything wrong:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport

It's said to redirect ports, but in my mind I would have to set like:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localhost listenport=4590 connectaddress=localhost connectport=4590
... and that just doesn't make sense.

what I want to do:

- type xphostname:4590/wiki or xpip:4590/wiki and see it working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a while I found out that our local proxy was blocking our network interconnections.
Just asked the network guys to make an exception and it worked.